# Realm entry corrupted immediately after write

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa, realm

We are running into a really strange issue with Realm (Swift). If we retrieve an entry immediately after writing it to the db it is completely different from the written one. What could possible cause this. Below is a screenshot from the debugger where it happens. The code to fetch the entry looks like this:

```
func fetchEntry(assetID: String) throws -> UploadInfo? {
    let realm = try Realm()
    return realm.objects(UploadInfo.self).filter { $0.assetID == assetID }.first
}
```

The entry class looks like this:

```
class UploadInfo: Object {

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "assetID"
    }

    override static func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["sessionID", "taskID"]
    }

    @objc dynamic var sessionID: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var taskID: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var totalBytesSent: Int64 = 0
    @objc dynamic var totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64 = 0
    @objc dynamic var downloadProgress: Float = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var uploadProgress: Float = 0.0

    @objc dynamic var fileURLPath: String = "" // path of file that is uploaded (i.e. multipart body)
    @objc dynamic var path: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var assetID: String = "" //PHAsset localIdentifier

    @objc dynamic var fileModificationTime: DegooTimestamp = 0
    @objc dynamic var fileSize: Int64 = 0 // unprocessedTotalFileDataLength
    @objc dynamic var fileChecksumBase64: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var fileChecksum: Data = Data(base64Encoded: "")!

    var fileURL: URL {
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURLPath)
    }

    func makeCopy() -> UploadInfo {
        let ui = UploadInfo()
        ui.sessionID = sessionID
        ui.taskID = taskID
        ui.totalBytesSent = totalBytesSent
        ui.totalBytesExpectedToSend = totalBytesExpectedToSend
        ui.downloadProgress = downloadProgress
        ui.uploadProgress = uploadProgress
        ui.fileURLPath = fileURLPath
        ui.path = path
        ui.assetID = assetID
        ui.fileModificationTime = fileModificationTime
        ui.fileSize = fileSize
        ui.fileChecksumBase64 = fileChecksumBase64
        ui.fileChecksum = fileChecksum
        return ui
    }
    }

    extension UploadInfo {
    var data: Data? {
        do {
            guard try FileManager.default.isFile(at: self.fileURL) else { return nil }
            return try Data(contentsOf: self.fileURL)
        } catch {
            Log.error(error)
            return nil
        }
    }

    var asset: PHAsset? {
        return PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [self.assetID], options: nil).firstObject
    }

    var shouldBeOptimized: Bool {
        guard let asset = self.asset else { return false }
        return ImageOptimizer.default.shouldBeReoptimized(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight)
    }

    func cleanUpUrls() {
        for url in urlsToCleanUp {
            do {
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.absoluteString) {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
                }
            } catch {
                Log.error(error)
            }
        }
    }

    var urlsToCleanUp: [URL] {
        let localAssetPathHelper = LocalAssetPathHelper()
        let assetFileName = localAssetPathHelper.fileName(for: URL(fileURLWithPath: self.path))
        let multipartBodyFileName = localAssetPathHelper.fileName(for: self.fileURL)
        return [
            URL(fileURLWithPath: localAssetPathHelper.path(for: multipartBodyFileName)),
            URL(fileURLWithPath: localAssetPathHelper.path(for: "/Photos/".appending(assetFileName))),
            URL(fileURLWithPath: localAssetPathHelper.path(for: "/Videos/".appending(assetFileName)))
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

We have tried this on both Realm 3.1.1 and 3.5.0.

Comment: Try to `print(storedEntry)`, Do not look at the values in the watcher ,because realm working single thread
try to print you find the correct values

Comment: objects in realm is lazy loading, so you just have pointer to data not the actual data. You'll get actual data when you access data, so just print in debugger object: `po storedEntry `